# Can you create a new filegroup for a table in a database that is live?

Tags: sql-server, filegroups

I have a SQL Server 12.0.5223.6 instance with a database on it.

I'm wondering if I can create a filegroup for one (or more) tables while it's running? Or does it have to have *no data* in the tables?

I *could* take the DB offline, but I can't take it offline for long. Right now all the data is inside `Data.mdf`. I'm hoping to split out some data from maybe three or four tables into separate filegroups.

Could this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely add a filegroup to a database while it's running, but it will have no data until you create a table in it, or rebuild a table onto the new filegroup.

This would mean dropping the clustered key on the table, and re-creating it on the filegroup:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IK_Example ON Example ( id ) ON NewFileGroup;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE Example ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Example PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id) ON NewFileGroup;
```

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15) on this one is pretty good.